# How to join elements with condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables: `regions` and `regions_access_purchases`.
I need a way to generate for user result table that have info about his current active purchase (access to region).

1. If user have no any purchased/accessed region he should get full list of regions.
2. If he have some purchased regions he should get full regions list with appended from right column about his `purchaseEndDate`.

I tried different joins, but all of them do not work:

```
SELECT region_id, translite_name,  "purchaseEndDate"  FROM regions
    FULL OUTER JOIN regions_access_purchases reg_purch ON regions.id = reg_purch.region_id
    WHERE user_id = 1 AND 
   "purchaseEndDate" > now()
```

I am getting only two regions, but I need to get full list of regions, with column from right with "purchaseEndDate". If "purchaseEndDate" is less than now it should not present, but region should be displayed in list.

Is it's possible to do such join?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30e72/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move condition from `WHERE` to `FROM` statement and change `FULL JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` you will get expected result:

```
SELECT * FROM regions
LEFT JOIN regions_access_purchases reg_purch ON regions.id = reg_purch.region_id AND user_id = 1 AND "purchaseEndDate" > now()
```

P.S. Not sure if you need to add purchaseEndDate to query, added it as you had it in your example.